# Attempt to concatenate global 'q2' (a table value) corona error

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am doing a corona project and i have been trying to insert 2 textbox value into my sqlite database. i am unable to do this and keep getting an error "Attempt to concatenate global 'q2' (a table value) " the below is a picture of the error.
[image: ERROR MESSAGE FROM CORONA]

```
 local widget = require "widget"
 local sqlite3 = require( "sqlite3" )
 local path = system.pathForFile( "data.db", system.DocumentsDirectory )
 local db = sqlite3.open( path )
 local tablesetup = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, q1, q2);]]
print( tablesetup )
db:exec( tablesetup )

_G.numericField = q1
local function textListener( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    -- User begins editing "numericField"
end
end

 -- Create text field
q1 = native.newTextField( 290, 150, 50, 30 )
q1.inputType = "number"
q1:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )


 _G.numericField1 = q2
local function textListener( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    -- User begins editing "numericField"
end
end

-- Create text field
q2 = native.newTextField( 290, 50, 50, 30 )
q2.inputType = "number"
q2:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )

saveData = function ( event )
   --textString = q1.text
   --textString = q2.text
  -- LINE 39 IS BELOW
local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..q1..[[',']]..q2..[['); ]]

    db:exec( tablefill )
    end

  savebutton = widget.newButton {
    left = 60,
    top = 250,
    default = "buttonGreen.png",
    over = "buttonGreenOver.png",
    label = "Update",
    embose = true,
    onRelease = saveData
    }
```

Is any able to help? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE (Line 36-41)

```
saveData = function ( event )
q1.text = "" 
q2.text = "" 
local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..q1..[[',']]..q2..[['); ]]
db:exec( tablefill )
end
```

Right now i am getting back the same error but this time it is at line 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating object `q1` and `q2` (which are represented as table), but then try to concatenate their values as strings:

```
q1 = native.newTextField( 290, 150, 50, 30 )
...
q2 = native.newTextField( 290, 50, 50, 30 )
...
local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..q1..[[',']]..q2..[['); ]]
```

I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to do, but this is not going to work, as the table values can't be concatenated this way.

Assuming `q1.text` gives you the value you are looking for, something like this should work:

```
local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..(q1.text or "")
  ..[[',']]..(q2.text or "")..[['); ]]
```

Note that concatenating values to form a SQl query makes it vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); you better be using placeholders instead.

Comment: q1 and q2 is numeric textbox. I am just trying to insert the value into sqlite DB. Are you able to help me with that?

Comment: You need to use `q1.text` as others have said, but if the value is not assigned, it will be `nil`, so you need to check for that: `(q1 or "NULL")` or `(q1 or "")`; same for q2.

Comment: hi, i have done it but there is still error. i have updated the question above you can take a look. thanks

Comment: I've added the example; I don't see you incorporating the suggestion in the updated question, so I posted how it may look like in the updated answer.

Comment: hi, there is no error now but in my DB it is a blank value (null). It only works when i remove q1.text = ""  and  q2.text = "" .  But when i remove the code my textbox does not refresh(clear previous value) when i hit the submit button. Do you know why is it so? or rather how i can i refresh all the textbox

Comment: Hi paul can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455857/corona-unable-to-submit-value-into-sqlite-database i realize I'm unable to integrate your answer there. Really need your helpppp! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

To get value of [TextField](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newTextField.html) object use `textField.text`. It returns string representing the contents of the native text input field. 
Instructions `q1.text`and `q2.text` should work for you.

Comment: it still shows (a nil value) error now. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: All of my code is in the question. are you able to help me pleaseeeee

Comment: To which line or instruction a nil value error refer to?

Comment: hi can you look at my question above? i have updated it. Thanks

Comment: hi can you take a loook at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455857/corona-unable-to-submit-value-into-sqlite-database this is my actual question. Thanks :DD