# Corona: unable to submit value into sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am using corona to develop my app. What am i trying to achieve here is to have 10 textbox for users to key in the value. After keying the value the data will store into sqlite once the user press submit. 
The code below have 10 loops and it is for the textbox. i have no problem displaying the textbox but my problem here is i am unable to store the value into sqlite database. Once i press submit **i have no error at all** but it just simply wont update the database.

```
local amt_padding = 4800

EBASbox1_label = display.newImage("img/scene15/box1.png")
EBASbox1_label.x = 360
EBASbox1_label.y = 50
EBASbox1_label.width = 680
EBASbox1_label.height = 60
scrollView:insert( EBASbox1_label )

EBASbox2_label = display.newImage("img/scene15/box2.png")
EBASbox2_label.x = 360
EBASbox2_label.y = 180
EBASbox2_label.width = 680
EBASbox2_label.height = 140
scrollView:insert( EBASbox2_label )



for i = 1, 10 do

    table_bg = display.newImage("img/scene15/table.png")
    table_bg.x = 370
    table_bg.y = 100 + (i * 450)
    table_bg.width = 700
    table_bg.height = 500

    scrollView:insert( table_bg )

    sno_text = display.newText( "",450,470,550,280, native.systemFont, 24 )
    sno_text.y = 10 + (i * 450)
    sno_text:setFillColor(0,0,0)
    sno_text.text =  tostring(i)
    scrollView:insert( sno_text )


    question_text = display.newText( "",300,470,550,250, native.systemFont, 24 )
    question_text.y = 50 + (i * 450)
    question_text:setFillColor(0,0,0)
    question_text.text = ebas_que[i]
    scrollView:insert( question_text )


    assessment_text = display.newText( "",300,470,550,250, native.systemFont, 24 )
    assessment_text.y = 290 + (i * 450)
    assessment_text:setFillColor(0,0,0)
    assessment_text.text = assessmentArr[i]
    scrollView:insert( assessment_text )
local ebasRating_Arr = display.newGroup()
local function textListener( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then
    -- Output resulting text from "defaultField"

print( event.target.text )

elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then
    print( event.newCharacters )
    print( event.oldText )
    print( event.startPosition )
    print( event.text )
    end
end
 -- Create text field
ebasRating_Arr = native.newTextField( 640, 150 + (i * 450), 100, 100 )
ebasRating_Arr.inputType = "number"
ebasRating_Arr:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
ebasRating_Arr.font = native.newFont( native.systemFontBold, 50 )
scrollView:insert(ebasRating_Arr )
end
```

The below is my code for inserting textbox data into database.

```
function saveResults()
        local q = [[UPDATE EBAS_DEP_POST SET rating1=']]..ebasRating_Arr[1] .. [[',rating2=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[2] .. [[',rating3=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[3] .. [[',rating4=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[4] .. [[',rating5=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[5] .. [[',rating6=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[6] .. [[',rating7=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[7] .. [[',rating8=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[8] .. [[',rating9=']].. ebasRating_Arr[9] .. [[',rating10=']].. ebasRating_Arr[10].. [[',rating11=']].. amtRating_Arr[1] .. [[',rating12=']] .. amtRating_Arr[2] .. [[',rating13=']] .. amtRating_Arr[3] .. [[',rating14=']] .. amtRating_Arr[4] .. [[',rating15=']] .. amtRating_Arr[5] .. [[',rating16=']] .. amtRating_Arr[6] .. [[',rating17=']] .. amtRating_Arr[7] .. [[',rating18=']] .. amtRating_Arr[8] .. [[',rating19=']] .. amtRating_Arr[9] .. [[',rating20=']] .. amtRating_Arr[10] .. [[',rating21=']].. amtRating_Arr[11] .. [[',rating22=']] .. amtRating_Arr[12] .. [[',rating23=']] .. amtRating_Arr[13] .. [[',rating24=']] .. amtRating_Arr[14] .. [[',rating25=']] .. amtRating_Arr[15] .. [[',rating26=']] .. amtRating_Arr[16] .. [[',rating27=']] .. amtRating_Arr[17] .. [[',rating28=']] .. amtRating_Arr[18] .. [[',rating29=']] .. amtRating_Arr[19] .. [[',rating30=']] .. amtRating_Arr[20] .. [[',ebas_score=']] .. ebasScore ..[[',amt_score=']] .. amtScore ..  [['WHERE id=']].. _G.EBAS_ID..[[';]]
        db:exec( q )
        print(db:errcode(), db:errmsg())

    end
```

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Hope you can help! thanks in advance :D

Comment: Does it call `saveResults`? Do you see the output printed? You only do Update, so if you have no records to update (nothing matches the WHERE condition), you won't see anything in the database and there won't be any errors. You can check `db:total_changes()` (http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_total_changes) to get the number of records modified.

Comment: yes it is named savResults. there is no output printed? i think i understand  db:total_changes()  but i am not sure how it can help me

Comment: sorry if im asking stupid question, im new to corona and lua

Comment: and i use update because there is a value of -1 in the cell by default

Comment: Your update code use filter `WHERE id=']].. _G.EBAS_ID`. Can you confirm that record with this id always exists in database before you call update?

Comment: @DenisKrasakov yes it definitely exists in the database